# Highlighting Specific Values In DateTimePIcker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Is there any way to make certain dates in a DateTimePicker look more prominent when it is expanded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to create a custom DateTimePicker control:
http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=70925

Comment: Blast, there is no simple way it seems.  Thanks for this info +1