# change the color of a specific date on date picker control for specified dates C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

I am working on a C#/WinForm Application.  The user when he activates the datepicker would like to see at a glance up and coming holidays by having the timepicker show them in red.

I have been playing around with the datetimepicker class events and properties below is an example of what I came up with:

```
DateTime decemberholiday =  new DateTime(2013,12,25);
        dateTimePicker1.Value = decemberholiday;
        if (dateTimePicker1.Value == decemberholiday) {

            dateTimePicker1.CalendarForeColor = Color.Red;
```

I know it is setting the date to the specific date instead of displaying the actual date but this was something i came up with for quick testing purposes.   When I run the program - nothing changes.  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have to create a custom control inheriting from DateTimePicker and override some drawing yourself.  See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933725/highlighting-specific-values-in-datetimepicker

Comment: You cannot override the way DTP or MonthCalendar paints, they are native Windows controls that don't support owner-draw.  All you've got is the MonthCalendar.BoldedDates property.