# Windows Form DatetTimePicker Control Pre Selected Dates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm wonder can we set dates highlighted on datetimepicker before shows calendar. something like this. **i know month calendar BoldedDates does the job** but is it possible to do same thing with datetimepicker

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlighting Specific Values In DateTimePIcker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933725/highlighting-specific-values-in-datetimepicker)

Comment: no as i explained i'm not looking solution with month calendar i'm looking for a way to know is it possible to extend datetimepicker to have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible using the existing Datapicker control.You might have to create a new custom DateTimePicker control.
Take a look http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/a-custom-datetimepicker-control-in-c.70925/